# Проблемы с интеграцией Reporting Services в VS2017

Tags: c#, report, reporting-services

Проблема заключается в том, что во время нормальной работы (создания того самого несчастного отчета) выскочило оповещение о зависании программы на какой-то там секунде и VS предложила отключить Reporting Services при следующей загрузке среды. По глупости и невнимательности мною было принято это предложение. А сейчас работу с RS восстановить никак не могу.

Подскажите, как можно это исправить?

В этой сфере я вообще новичок, так что не судите за глупый вопрос)

Comment: В настройках плагинов надо включить обратно :)

Comment: @NewView , спасибо. Все оказалась также просто, как и думал)